# How to access scala object inside scala class in java?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have scala class like:

```
class A {
  object B {
    def c(d: Int) = d + 4
  }
}
```

How do i access function `c` from a java code?

Edit: assume that I can't change scala class anyhow.

Edit#2:
Here is example of

```
public class Q {
    public void qwe() {
        A a = new A();
        a.B().c(4); //Cannot resolve method 'B' in 'A'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`object B` from class gets converted to public method `B()` which you can access as follows:

```java
  A a = new A();
  System.out.println(a.B().c(4));
```

### Under The Hood

**A.scala**

```scala
class A {
  object B {
    def c(d: Int) = d + 4
  }
}
```

Above class when compiled to java looks like below

```sh
scalac A.scala
```

```sh
javap -p A.class
```

```java
public class A {
  private volatile A$B$ B$module;
  public A$B$ B();
  private final void B$lzycompute$1();
  public A();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in idea. And Gradle also throw error when i try to compile it.
here is example of java class
```
public class Q {
    public void qwe() {
        A a = new A();
        a.B().d(4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Idea does not understand, maybe bug with intellij. You can still run and should print 8